# How to make dynamic tab bar react ntaive

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a main page with three tabs in my app.
And user can log in in three modes: seller, buyer, and driver.
But when the user logs in as a driver, I want to show two tab bars.
This is my tab bar navigation source code:

```
const Home = createStackNavigator(
    {
        HomeScreen: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false,
            }
        },
        
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
    }
);

const ShoppingCart = createStackNavigator(
    {
        ShoppingCartScreen: {
            screen: ShoppingCartScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false,
            }
        },
        
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'ShoppingCartScreen',
    }
);

const OrderHistory = createStackNavigator(
    {
        ProfileScreen: {
            screen: ProfileScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false,
            }
        },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'ProfileScreen',
    }
);

const TabNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home,
        ShoppingCart,
        OrderHistory,
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                //   let IconComponent = Icon;
                //   let iconName;
                
                    return <Image source={ImageUrl} color={tintColor} style={{ width: 99, height: 46 }} />
                }
            },
        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'white',
            showLabel: false,               
            labelStyle: {
                marginTop: -10,
                marginBottom: 10,
                fontSize: 15,
            },
        },
    },
);


export default createAppContainer(TabNavigation);
```

And this is RootNavigation source code.

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import TabBarScreen from './TabBarNavigation'

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        LoginScreen: {
            screen: LoginScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false
            }
        },
        SignUpScreen: {
            screen: SignUpScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false
            }
        },
        ForgotPasswordScreen: {
            screen: ForgotPasswordScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false
            }
        },
        DispensariesSignupScreen: {
            screen: DispensariesSignupScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false
            }
        },
        DriverSignupScreen: {
            screen: DriverSignupScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false
            }
        },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen'
    }
)

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
    Tabbar: {
        screen: TabBarScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false
        }
    },
})

// const App = createAppContainer(RootNavigation);
// export default App;


export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            Splash: SplashScreen,
            Auth: AuthStack,
            App: AppStack
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'Splash'
        }
    )
);
```

So when the user logs in as a driver, I want to show only two bar: ShoppingCart, OrderHistory,
how can I make the tab bar dynamically?